# Can a sqlalchemy relationship be accessed using a new session?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When using `yield_per` I am forced to use a separate session if I want to perform another query while the result from the `yield_per` query have not yet been all fetched.

Let's take this models for our example:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

Here are three ways to achieve the same thing, but only the first one works:

```
query = session.query(Parent).yield_per(5)
for p in query:
    print(p.id)

    # 1: Using a new session (will work):
    c = newsession.query(Child).filter_by(parent_id=p.id).first()
    print(c.id)

    # 2: Using the same session (will not work):
    c = session.query(Child).filter_by(parent_id=p.id).first()
    print(c.id)

    # 3: Using the relationship (will not work):
    c = p.children[0]
    print(c.id)
```

Indeed (when using mysql) both 2 and 3 will throw an exception and stop execution with the following error: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

My question is, is there a way I can make relationship lookup work in this context ? Is there maybe a way to trick sqlalchemy into using a new session when the first one is busy ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [selectinload](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#select-in-loading), as it supports eagerly loading with yield_per.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

query = session.query(
    Parent
).options(
    sa.orm.selectinload(Parent.children)
).yield_per(5)

for parent in query:
    for child in parent.children:
        print(child.id)
```